# Ionic - Call 2 subscribe functions and wait until they finish

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, subscribe

I'm using Ionic to build a mobile app.
In it I have 2 API calls, that can run at the same time, after they both finished, I need to change the data in the second response according to data from the first response. So I need to make sure that when I ran the third function (to manipulate the data) it's after both API calls have finished.

API call 1:

```
getExpenses() {
    this.api.getExpenses().subscribe(response => {
        this.expenses = response;
    });
}
```

API call 2:

```
getPayMethods() {
    this.api.getPayMethods().subscribe(response => {
      this.methods = response;
    });
}
```

Function to manipulate the data:

```
extendPayMethodData(){
   modifyData();
}
```

In the `constructor` I run:

```
this.getPayMethods();
this.getExpenses();
this.extendPayMethodData();
```

But this doesn't work because when `extendPayMethodData` is called the other functions didn't finish yet.
I have tried to use:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.getPayMethods(),
    this.getExpenses()
).subscribe(_ => this.extendPayMethodData())
```

But then I get this error:

> Error:(26, 7) TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise'.

What should be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `this.getPayMethods` nor `this.getExpenses` return their observables, which is why you see that error.

Try this instead:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.api.getPayMethods(),
    this.api.getExpenses()
).subscribe(_ => this.extendPayMethodData())
```